# Generate several multiplots using two dataframes with the same column names in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames (data1 and data2) with the **same column names** called A, B, C, D, G, F, G, H,... .
I want to  create several graphs with both plots of data1 and data2 inside, by combining different columns. So that I can call the function as:

```
getPlot(data1, data2, A, B, C, D)
getPlot(data1, data2, B, F, G, H)
getPlot(data1, data2, A, C, F, B)
```

...

and whatever combination of columns.

I wrote the function like this:

```
getPlot = function(df1, df2, M1, M2, M3, M4){
   png(file=paste("",M1,"",M2,"vs",M3,"",M4,"_plot.png", sep=""), width=800, height=800 )

   plot(df1$M1-df1$M2, df1$M3-df1$M4, xlab = M1-M2, ylab = M3-M4, type="p", pch=20, cex=0.5, col="red")

   points(df2$M1-df2$M2, df2$M3-df2$M4, type="p", pch=20, cex=0.5, col="red")

   dev.off()
}
```

but the problem is that I'm calling the function with the name of the columns

```
 getPlot(data1, data2, A, B, C, D)
```

So as they are not existing variables, getPlot cannot understand what I would like to get... therefore, for example, df1$M1 means nothing for him...

How can I do this in order to get simply different plots with different combinations of columns?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function:

```
getPlot = function(df1, df2, M1, M2, M3, M4)
{
png(file=paste("",M1,"",M2,"vs",M3,"",M4,"_plot.png", sep=""), width=800, height=800 )

plot(df1[[M1]]-df1[[M2]], df1[[M3]]-df1[[M4]], xlab = paste0(M1,"-",M2), ylab = paste0(M3,"-",M4), type="p", pch=20, cex=0.5, col="red")

points(df2[[M1]]-df2[[M2]], df2[[M3]]-df2[[M4]], type="p", pch=20, cex=0.5, col="red")
dev.off()
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
getPlot(data1, data2, "A", "B", "C", "D")
```

Here, `M1` and `M2` are strings, and we use the fact that:

```
 data1$A
```

and

```
data1[["A"]]
```

are both ways of accessing column `A` of `data1`.

Comment: Thanks, that works! But in your function you must add a ")" at the end of ylab expression: ylab = paste0(M3, "-", M4). And as M1, M2, M3, M4 they are already strings, within the function we must call the columns as: df1[[M1]] without " ".  If you correct this in your post I will select it as the correct answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yeah, I missed those. I've corrected them.